# How to continue loops vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Apologies if this has been posted already - I couldn't find one specific to Excel (also for my poor code, I am poorly experienced with VBA). 
I'm trying to collate multiple files into one workbook, under different worksheets. Most of it is working - but within the If Else statement, if the condition is met, the loop breaks, rather than continuing on with the rest of the files in the folder. The Else part does loop. I thought that `Do While filename <> ""` would override the if/then statement.

It didn't work with me just adding "And Loop" (guessing that's not valid code), so I'm at a loss as to what I should add, or whether I should go around this another way.

Thank you for your help!

```
Sub AllFiles()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim master As Workbook
    Set master = ThisWorkbook

    folderPath = "C:\Users\Charmaine\Documents\Excel Files"
    master.Activate

    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

    filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsm")
    Do While filename <> ""
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        ActiveSheet.Range("F1:G242").Select
        Selection.Copy
        master.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        wb.Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveWindow.Close

        filename = Dir

        If ActiveSheet.Range("R1") = "C3" Then Sheets.Add.[after].Name = valuenewsheet Else

    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `... valuenewsheet Else` should probably not have that `Else` on the end.

Comment: Yes if you remove `Else` then the loop is triggered no matter what. The `If` `Then` statement simply adds a new sheet if the condition is met.

Comment: I tried this but I get a "Run-time error '424': Object required" error after it makes the new sheet.

Comment: What is the value of `valuenewsheet` when your end-of-loop `If` statement is evaluating it? It's undeclared in this `Sub` so either it's a global or you're not using `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. If you're not using `Option Explicit`, that's your #1 step - it will prevent you from mis-typing a variable name. If you do that, VBA will "helpfully" declare a new, empty variable for you...

Comment: Also, the 1-line `If... Then... Else` statements are kinda hard to read. It's a style thing, VBA allows for them all on 1 line, but it's reasonably uncommon and takes more mental energy to grok, and invites more side-scrolling to read (as you'll note in your posted code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone.
I ended up changing the last line to

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

I thought that 'valuenewsheet' meant that it would count up the next available sheet name, but seems to be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do
'code
Loop While filename <>
```

Interestingly, I have had the issue of a do while loop exiting while the While statement isn't met. Transferring the While statement to after the Loop statement worked for me.

Comment: I've tried this too but it is also not working after adding a new sheet, with the same error. Is there something wrong with this part? "Sheets.Add.[after].Name = valuenewsheet"

Comment: The only problem with this method is that it presumes _at least one_ `filename` exists and will blow up on the `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)` if it doesn't.

Comment: I don't see where you populate the variable 'valuenewsheet', I'm assuming this is causing the error.

Comment: @TimStack [that's what he said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53594238/how-to-continue-loops-vba#comment94051713_53594238)...  :)

Comment: I never get away with claiming credit for someone else's solution!

Comment: @TimStack - LOL!